# Question about redirect to text not work in Android with ADB shell

Tags: linux, shell, redirect

I am trying to run cpu2006 in Android vi `adb`, the compiled binary of cpu2006 is working here, but I need to use command `time` to get the time for each sub-test, but the text that redirect by time is empty although the screen have such output:

```
real    242.697
user    241.500062
sys     0.179010
```

I put the sub-test command into a sh file which was named as doit.sh:

```
../run_base_ref_gcc12.0000/bwaves_base.gcc12 2>> bwaves.err
```

here is how I run the test:
`time taskset -a 80 doit.sh > 410.bwaves.txt`

```
real    242.697
user    241.500062
sys     0.179010
```

410.bwaves.txt is empty.

**update:**
I have find a way:
{ time taskset -a 80 ./doit.sh ; } 2> ${output}.txt

Comment: The `-a` flag doesn't work with redirect. From the `time` man page:  -a, --append Append the resource use information to the output file instead of overwriting it.  This option is only useful with the `-o` or `--output` option. So I would try write to file that way. LMK if this works for you.

Comment: @Uberhumus -a is used for command "taskset" to special the cpu mask. I try time -o, but  adb report :/system/bin/sh: time: -o: unknown option .

Comment: What shell are you running? Is `/system/bin/sh` bash? Does your version of `time` have the `-o` option?

Comment: @Uberhumus there is not bash in android with adb. I have found a way to do this :{ time taskset -a 80 ./doit.sh ; } 2> output.txt